# Получение значения из EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть EditText поле. КАК передать то, что в него ввели в string??
Пытался следующим способом, но подсвечивает красным text между EditText и onString как Unresolved reference:

```
var editText = EditText.text.onString()
```

вот код кнопки

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

насколько знаю - не нужно где то доп. объявлять, так что просто (естественно после MainActivity класса):

```
    fun thirdact(view: View){
        var editText = EditText.text.onString()

    }
```

Comment: покажите как объявили данное текстовое поле, приложите разметку где есть данное текстовое поле.

Comment: Правил) Можете посмотреть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял как вы хотели получить доступ к такому полю для ввода. Если использовать Kotlin Android Extensions, то можно обратиться напрямую к полю из класса активности:

```
edit1.text
```

либо объявить данное поле и потом присвоить ему значение:

```
val field = findViewById< EditText>(R.id.edit1)
val string = field.text
```

либо использовать dataBinding. Подключив при этом его в build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

и конвертировав ваш макет в dataBinding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         !!!! вот тут ваше наполнение может находится, родительский контейнер может быть другим
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</layout>
```

и дальше найти по ID:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity); 
binding.edit1.text
```

[Вот есть](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) полезная ссылка по dataBinding и вот [туториал](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/551-urok-18-data-binding-osnovy.html)